# How to define lens into sum-type inside Map-like container?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens, lenses

I can define the needed `Lens'` manually:

```
type Key = String
type Val = Int
type Foo  = Map Key (Either Val Bool)

ll :: String -> Lens' Foo (Maybe Int)
ll k f m = f mv <&> \r -> case r of
  Nothing -> maybe m (const (Map.delete k m)) mv
  Just v' -> Map.insert k (Left v') m
  where mv = Map.lookup k m >>= maybeLeft
        maybeLeft (Left v') = Just v'
        maybeLeft (Right _) = Nothing
```

And it works like:

```
x, y :: Foo
x = Map.empty
y = Map.fromList [("foo", Right True)]

>>> x ^. ll "foo"
Nothing

>>> x & ll "foo" ?~ 1
fromList [("foo",Left 1)]

>>> (x & ll "foo" ?~ 1) ^. ll "foo"
Just 1

>>> (x & ll "foo" ?~ 1) ^. ll "bar"
Nothing

>>> x & ll "foo" ?~ 1 & ll "foo" .~ Nothing
fromList []

>>> y ^. ll "foo"
Nothing

>>> y & ll "foo" ?~ 1
fromList [("foo",Left 1)]

>>> y & ll "foo" .~ Nothing
fromList [("foo",Right True)]
```

I verified that definition is lawful:

```
-- Orphan instance is ok-ish in this case :)
instance (Ord k, Arbitrary k, Arbitrary v) => Arbitrary (Map k v) where
  arbitrary = Map.fromList <$> arbitrary

-- 1) You get back what you put in:
lensLaw1 :: Foo -> Key -> Maybe Val -> Property
lensLaw1 s k v = view (ll k) (set (ll k) v s) === v

-- 2) Putting back what you got doesn't change anything:
lensLaw2 :: Foo -> Key -> Property
lensLaw2 s k = set (ll k) (view (ll k) s) s === s

-- 3) Setting twice is the same as setting once:
lensLaw3 :: Foo -> Key -> Maybe Val -> Maybe Val -> Property
lensLaw3 s k v v' = set (ll k) v' (set (ll k) v s) === set (ll k) v' s
```

**So the question**: *can the `ll` be defined using [`at`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.7/docs/Control-Lens-At.html#v:at) and [`_Left`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.7/docs/Control-Lens-Prism.html#v:_Left)?*

Maybe with some kind of `prismToLens :: Prism' a b -> Lens' (Maybe a) (Maybe b)`, you can do `at k . prismToLens _Left`. Yet I'm not sure if `prismToLens` makes sense? Hoogle isn't that helpful with `lens` :(

*EDIT* seems that third law doesn't hold always. Easy to find counter-example if you change `Key` to be `Bool`. Yet in my application the `Map` is actually dependent, i.e. the sum branch depends on the key, so the `Lens` law should hold (if I access `foo`, I know it should be `Left` or not exist at all).

Comment: Ick, non-law-abiding things are icky. Can you wrap this `Map` up in some fashion to express the invariant you later rely on?

Comment: @dfeuer, yes in the real app the implementation is hidden. Yet for example [`non`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.7/docs/Control-Lens-Iso.html#v:non) is stretching the reality too :)

Answer (score 1):

For now I go with:

```
prismToLens :: Prism' a b -> Lens' (Maybe a) (Maybe b)
prismToLens p = lens getter setter
  where getter s = s >>= (^? p)
        setter _ b = (p#) <$> b
```

so I can define `ll` like:

```
ll' :: Key -> Lens' Foo (Maybe Val)
ll' k = at k . prismToLens _Left
```

Controrary to the "lens" defined in the question, for this one 2nd law doesn't hold:

```
-- 2) Putting back what you got doesn't change anything:
-- Doesn't hold
-- >>> quickCheck $ lensLaw2' (Map.fromList [(True,Right False)]) True
-- fromList [] /= fromList [(True,Right False)]
lensLaw2' :: Foo -> Key -> Property
lensLaw2' s k = set (ll' k) (view (ll' k) s) s === s
```

But with original the third law didn't hold:

```
-- 3) Setting twice is the same as setting once:
-- Doesn't hold
-- >>> quickCheck $ lensLaw3 (Map.fromList [(False, Right False)]) False (Just 0) Nothing
-- fromList [] /= fromList [(True,Right False)]
lensLaw3 :: Foo -> Key -> Maybe Val -> Maybe Val -> Property
lensLaw3 s k v v' = set (ll k) v' (set (ll k) v s) === set (ll k) v' s
```

---

As said in the question as I have dependend map, this is ok. When accessing some key `k`, there shouldn't ever be `Right` value, if I expect there to be `Left`. Taking this into the account, using `prismToLens` is actually better. Still searching for a better name though.

---

After remembering [`non`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.7/docs/Control-Lens-Iso.html#v:non), I altered the answer to use:

```
prismToIso :: Prism' a b -> Iso' (Maybe a) (Maybe b)
prismToIso p = iso t f
  where t a = a >>=  (^? p)
        f b = (p#) <$> b -- no unused param as in `prismToLens`!
```

Which resembles [`mapping`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.7/docs/Control-Lens-Iso.html#v:mapping). The law properties behaved the same as with `prismToLens`. This gives rise to the new questio:  which one is better or worse, `prismToIso` or `prismToLens`. And why?

---

The full runnable example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
module Lens where

import Control.Applicative
import Control.Lens
import Data.Map as Map
import Test.QuickCheck

type Key = Bool
type Val = Int
type Foo  = Map Key (Either Val Bool)

ll :: Key -> Lens' Foo (Maybe Val)
ll k f m = f mv <&> \r -> case r of
  Nothing -> maybe m (const (Map.delete k m)) mv
  Just v' -> Map.insert k (Left v') m
  where mv = Map.lookup k m >>= maybeLeft
        maybeLeft (Left v') = Just v'
        maybeLeft (Right _) = Nothing

prismToLens :: Prism' a b -> Lens' (Maybe a) (Maybe b)
prismToLens p = lens getter setter
  where getter s = s >>= (^? p)
        setter _ b = (p#) <$> b

ll' :: Key -> Lens' Foo (Maybe Val)
ll' k = at k . prismToLens _Left

x, y :: Foo
x = Map.empty
y = Map.fromList [(True, Right True)]

{-
>>> x ^. ll "foo"
Nothing

>>> x & ll "foo" ?~ 1
fromList [("foo",Left 1)]

>>> (x & ll "foo" ?~ 1) ^. ll "foo"
Just 1

>>> (x & ll "foo" ?~ 1) ^. ll "bar"
Nothing

>>> x & ll "foo" ?~ 1 & ll "foo" .~ Nothing
fromList []

>>> y ^. ll "foo"
Nothing

>>> y & ll "foo" ?~ 1
fromList [("foo",Left 1)]

>>> y & ll "foo" .~ Nothing
fromList [("foo",Right True)]
-}

-- Orphan instance is ok-ish in this case :)
instance (Ord k, Arbitrary k, Arbitrary v) => Arbitrary (Map k v) where
  arbitrary = Map.fromList <$> arbitrary
  shrink = Prelude.map Map.fromList . shrink . Map.toList

-- 1) You get back what you put in:
lensLaw1 :: Foo -> Key -> Maybe Val -> Property
lensLaw1 s k v = view (ll k) (set (ll k) v s) === v

-- 2) Putting back what you got doesn't change anything:
lensLaw2 :: Foo -> Key -> Property
lensLaw2 s k = set (ll k) (view (ll k) s) s === s

-- 3) Setting twice is the same as setting once:
-- Doesn't hold
-- >>> quickCheck $ lensLaw3 (Map.fromList [(False, Right False)]) False (Just 0) Nothing
-- fromList [] /= fromList [(True,Right False)]
lensLaw3 :: Foo -> Key -> Maybe Val -> Maybe Val -> Property
lensLaw3 s k v v' = set (ll k) v' (set (ll k) v s) === set (ll k) v' s

-- Using prismToLens defined "lens"

-- 1) You get back what you put in:
lensLaw1' :: Foo -> Key -> Maybe Val -> Property
lensLaw1' s k v = view (ll' k) (set (ll' k) v s) === v

-- 2) Putting back what you got doesn't change anything:
-- Doesn't hold
-- >>> quickCheck $ lensLaw2' (Map.fromList [(True,Right False)]) True
-- fromList [] /= fromList [(True,Right False)]
lensLaw2' :: Foo -> Key -> Property
lensLaw2' s k = set (ll' k) (view (ll' k) s) s === s

-- 3) Setting twice is the same as setting once:
lensLaw3' :: Foo -> Key -> Maybe Val -> Maybe Val -> Property
lensLaw3' s k v v' = set (ll' k) v' (set (ll' k) v s) === set (ll' k) v' s
```